# Decrypt Volume while bootup with keyfile OR password

Tags: encryption, luks, cryptsetup

A dynamically growing .img-file is mounted to my user's home directory. Its file system is btrfs and it's encrypted via LUKS.

Keyslot 0: A file created by

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=<some file> bs=512 count=8
```

Keyslot 1: A password for manual decrition.

The keyfile is located on a thumbdrive which, when inserted, is automatically mounted at

```
/mnt/clavis
```

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- On boottime the system tries to find /mnt/clavis/home.key
- If this fails (e.g. if the thumbdrive isn't inserted): Prompt for password.

The following setups are working:

```
/etc/crypttab
home <path to image> none luks,discard
```

And (when the thumbdrive is inserted):

```
/etc/crypttab
home <path to image> /mnt/clavis/home.key luks,discard
```

However it does not work when the thumbdrive isn't inserted. It just hangs for some time and then continues to boot without mounting /home/. I can then manually luksOpen the image but invoking cryptdisks_start home fails.

What am I doing wrong? Tutorials on how to use password- and keyfile-based encryption simultaneously are hard to find.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.